# plotting geometric objects. Sci-lab

Tags: scilab

By using Sci-lab I need to draw triangle cicrle and rectangular (separately, of course). the most difficult for me is triangle, I have no idea how to plot them

Comment: thank you guys. I found how to plot circle and rectangle.. All I need is trianngle now. Any guidance please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotting is rather trivial. See the [plot](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/plot.html) command reference.

There are shorter ways, but for easiest understanding just plot the three sides as three lines.

For instance if you have a triangle with the corner coordinates at (x,y) = [0,0],[5,10],[10,0]. Plot three lines between these points.

```
plot([0,5],[0,10])
plot([5,10],[10,0])
plot([0,10],[0,0])
```